# how to modify the value objects in a $session array variable

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => product Object
        (
            [prodId] => 1
            [prodName] => test
            [prodPrice] => 23
        )
[1] => product Object
    (
        [prodId] => 2
        [prodName] => test2
        [prodPrice] => 43
    )

)
```

Comment: Please add code samples of what you have tried. If you haven't tried anything please consult a tutorial or the manual (php.net).

Answer (score 0):

Simulating your array, and accessing externally using public parameters:

```
class product {
    public $prodId;
    public $prodName;
    public $prodPrice;

    function __construct($x,$y,$z) {
        $this->prodId = $x;
        $this->prodName = $y;
        $this->prodPrice = $z;
    }
}

$products[0] = new product(1,'test',23);
$products[1] = new product(2,'test2',43);
print_r($products);
echo "<BR>";

$products[0]->prodId = 10;
$products[0]->prodName = 'test1';
print_r($products);
```